# Por um lado / Por outro - Qual frase está mais bem construída?

Tags: gramática

Tenho uma dúvida sobre a construção de uma frase.

Qual destas duas opções é melhor? Ou, ainda, existe uma terceira opção mais correta?

> - Se, por um lado, essa pessoa ou empresa fica encarregada pelos tributos e pelo registro, por outro ela garante sua confidencialidade.
> - Se, por um lado, essa pessoa ou empresa fica encarregada pelos tributos e pelo registro, por outro, ela garante sua confidencialidade.

Comment: Para confirmar: a sua única dúvida é sobre a colocação da vírgula após "por outro", confere? Eu não teria dúvida em usar com vírgula.

Comment: Que curioso, @stafusa, eu não teria dúvida em usar *sem* vírgula... :)

Comment: @ANeves :-) Pois é, num primeiro momento não tenho justificativa embasada para minha opinião - por isso também só coloquei num comentário e não numa resposta. Eu chuto que é mesmo mais uma questão de estilo e bom senso, mas fico no aguardo de resposta.

Comment: Eu usaria apenas duas vírgulas: após "um lado" e após "registro".

Comment: @Centaurus, possivelmente eu poria uma única após "registro". Eu compreendo uma só vírgula após "por um lado", e muitas vezes tenho ganas de escrever assim (reflete a entoação da frase), mas na pontuação moderna isso seria uma opção duvidosa: a frase básica é "se essa pessoa fica...", e quando intercalas qualquer coisa (como "por um lado") a norma atual é pôr duas vírgulas ou nenhuma.

Comment: construida melhor, mais bem, fica bem estranho....

Answer (score 1):

**Com vírgula.** Repare que as duas frases podem ser escritas de forma independente:

> Por um lado, essa pessoa ou empresa fica encarregada pelos tributos e pelo registo. Por outro, ela garante sua confidencialidade.

mais uma vez, preservando a vírgula.

As expressões "por um lado" e "por outro" **são conectores de discurso que "conectam" duas orações distintas:**

1. Essa pessoa ou empresa fica encarregue pelos tributos e pelo registo.
2. Ela garante sua confidencialidade

Por isso, é mais correto escrevê-los entre vírgulas -ou, melhor ainda, separados por um **;**.

Answer (score -1):

Eu escreveria a frase assim:

```
Se por um lado essa pessoa ou empresa fica encarregada pelos tributos e pelo registro, por outro garante a sua confidencialidade.
```

Eu, particularmente, não gosto das palavras `ele`, `ela`, `você` e etc. Acho que essas palavras enfeiam as frases e só devem ser usadas apenas quando necessárias.